# How to enable pam and disallow root/password login for ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

I want do disable password and root login via ssh. I followed this guide https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-disable-ssh-password-login-on-linux/. It suggests making the following changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

PasswordAuthentication no

UsePAM no

PermitRootLogin no
```

But now I want to be able to receive email notifications if someone logs in via ssh. For that I added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/login-notify.sh
```

To make this work I need to set `UsePam` to yes.

*My Question:* Do I need further modification of `PAM` to make sure, that password and root login is disabled? And what is if `PAM` is configured to allow password and root login, but `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` disallows root and password login?

Comment: Any tutorial that says to set `UsePAM no` without a very lengthy explanation should be treated as unreliable and ignored in its entirety. This should almost always be set to `yes` as too many things break if it is disabled.

Comment: If I set usePam to yes and permitRootLogin/passwordAuthentication to no, can I be sure that rootLogin and passwort login is disabled?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?